# Multiple thermocouples on raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, temperature

I am pretty new to the GPIO part of the raspberry Pi.  When I need pins I normally just use Arduino.  However I would really like this project to be consolidated to one platform if possible, I would like to do it all on the PI.

So I have three (3) [MAX31855](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31855.pdf) boards and type K Thermocouples.  I just don't know where to go with hooking up the other two.  I don't know if I can just use any other pins (besides power and ground pins) for the MISO, CSO, and SCLK pins.  This may sound like a rookie question but like I said I'm used to using arduino for this stuff.  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

I'm using code from https://github.com/Tuckie/max31855

```
from max31855 import MAX31855, MAX31855Error

cs_pin=24
clock_pin=23
data_pin=22
unit="f"
thermocouple1=MAX31855(cs_pin, clock_pin, data_pin, units)
print(thermocouple.get())
thermocouple.cleanup()
```

Comment: you could use a TH7 which has 7 thermo-couple inputs on one PCB for the raspberry pi https://github.com/robin48gx/TH7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can share the `MISO` and `SCLK` lines among the devices, and then each device will need its own `CS`.  Something like:

[image: Multi Drop SPI]

In this case `Master` is the Pi, and Slaves are the MAX31855's. SS (Slave Select) is the same as CS (Chip Select).

```
from max31855 import MAX31855, MAX31855Error

cs_pin_1=24
clock_pin=23
data_pin=22
cs_pin_2=21
cs_pin_3=20
units = "f"

thermocouple1=MAX31855(cs_pin_1, clock_pin, data_pin, units)
thermocouple2=MAX31855(cs_pin_2, clock_pin, data_pin, units)
thermocouple3=MAX31855(cs_pin_3, clock_pin, data_pin, units)
```

Comment: Checked and up voted.  I apparently don't have enough reputation to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TH7 pi hat which allows up to seven thermocouple inputs.
This PCB uses the standard python SPI interface. Python Code plus 
documentation below.
https://github.com/robin48gx/TH7