# Multiple thermocouples on raspberry pi - NAN reading when in electrical contact

Tags: raspberry-pi3, temperature

I have 2 K-type thermocouples running on individual MAX31855 boards on a Raspberry Pi 3. 
The MAX31855 boards share a CLK pin but have separate CS and DO pins, similar to the set up given here:
[Multiple thermocouples on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622224/multiple-thermocouples-on-raspberry-pi)

Everything works great until i place both thermocouples on a metal surface which causes both thermocouple readings to be "NAN". I guess its a grounding issue? Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can glue them with epoxy to the devices you are monitoring. Thermo-couples should not be connected together electrically and it sounds as though you may have grounded them. Also, I don't know how the MAX works precisely, but in order to be able to read negative temperatures, the thermo-couples are probably biased UP slightly (maybe 10mV).

If you ground them this means they will read a voltage that translates as -10mV which would be a temperature lower than absolute zero. Hence, NaN, i.e. not a number.

I do know how the TH7 works and the python code for driving that (its a raspberry pi thing) is here https://github.com/robin48gx/TH7